# Manually creating document in Cosmos DB collection

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I want to manually create a document in my Cosmos DB collection but "Create" option in Document Explorer is disabled -- see below. I used to be able to do this.

[image]

How do we create documents manually now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Sam: looks like you're seeing the old version of the Data Explorer. Try cleaning browser cache or logging in to the portal with another browser. You should see "New Document" button when you click on your documents collection in Data Explorer.